# When training a Keras model is there a way to have the GPU to take small breaks (sleeps) in between set epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

My Keras model is currently looking at a lot of data and I personally don't feel comfortable letting my GPU reach 85 degrees...is there a way during a set amount epochs to tell my GPU to take a break?

I understand I could just break down the process into multiple training cycles but because I am using a ReduceLROnPlateau in my callback on an RNN model I would still like the entire training process to be done in one training cycle with the GPU taking small breaks to allow for longer training times with less risk to my personal hardware.

(Not adding code due to this just being a general question.)

Comment: [The GPU is just fine at 85 degrees and it has overheating protection anyway](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2752/~/nvidia-gpu-maximum-operating-temperature-and-overheating).

Comment: It looks like you could simply add a `LambdaCallback` and define `on_epoch_begin`  as `lambda e, l: time.sleep(10) if e % 10 == 0 else None` or similar.

Comment: Usually, it is my friend told me how his own personal hit 85+ degrees in a 2 day period and crashed losing all his progress. So I am just worried and saving 20 minutes or so to save 7-12 hours is a pretty good deal in my book. Regardless thank you for reassurance. But I am interested in this LambdaCallback now...

Comment: I just added e!=0 and it worked exactly as I needed thanks again!